# I cannot send email with sql server smtp

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, email

I am trying to send an email with sql server 2012. I tried to follow a couple of tutorials but couldn't succeed.

Here is the exception I am getting.

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000]

and my code is this

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Test2', @recipients='test@Example.com',    
                              @subject='Test message', @body='This is the body'
```

My problem is I am using another database schema called Akkord. But I can only access `sp_send_dbmail` through `msdb` database. I should either give permission to use `msdb`'s email procedure or I should do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the user who is trying to send Database Mail does not have the required permissions to execute sp_send_dbmail. To be able to send mail using Database mail, a user has to be a member of the ‘DatabaseMailUserRole’ role in the msdb database. Here’s how to add the user to this role

```
USE msdb
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole',
@membername = 'YourDomain\YourDomainUser';
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to register your user in msdb database also.
This [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188719%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) may help you.